# Import JSON into ClickHouse

Tags: database, clickhouse

I create table with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE event(
    date Date,
    src UInt8,
    channel UInt8,
    deviceTypeId UInt8,
    projectId UInt64,
    shows UInt32,
    clicks UInt32,
    spent Float64
) ENGINE = MergeTree(date, (date, src, channel, projectId), 8192);
```

Raw data looks like:

```
{ "date":"2016-03-07T10:00:00+0300","src":2,"channel":18,"deviceTypeId ":101, "projectId":2363610,"shows":1232,"clicks":7,"spent":34.72,"location":"Unknown", ...}
...
```

Files with data loaded with the following command:

```
cat *.data|sed 's/T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]+0300//'| clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO event FORMAT JSONEachRow"
```

*clickhouse-client* throw exception:

```
Code: 117. DB::Exception: Unknown field found while parsing JSONEachRow format: location: (at row 1)
```

Is it possible to skip fields from JSON object that not presented in table description?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The latest ClickHouse release (v1.1.54023) supports `input_format_skip_unknown_fields` user option which eneables skipping of unknown fields for JSONEachRow and TSKV formats.

Try

```
clickhouse-client -n --query="SET input_format_skip_unknown_fields=1; INSERT INTO event FORMAT JSONEachRow;"
```

See more details in [documentation](https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#input_format_skip_unknown_fields).

Comment: There is more convenient way to specify settings in clickhouse-client:

clickhouse-client --input_format_skip_unknown_fields=1 --query="INSERT INTO event FORMAT JSONEachRow;"

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to skip unknown fields.

You may create temporary table with additional field, `INSERT` data into it, and then do `INSERT` `SELECT` into final table. Temporary table may have Log engine and `INSERT` into that "staging" table will work faster than into final `MergeTree` table.

It is relatively easy to add possibility to skip unknown fields into code (something like setting 'format_skip_unknown_fields').